# How to get Notification from standalone class (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsnotificationcenter

I want to call method in a class as soon as observer get Notification in another one. The problem is that I cannot call one class from another, because I will get recursion call then.

1) Controller class with Player instance:

```
//  PlayerController.swift
//  player

import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class NowPlayingController: NSObject {

    var musicPlayer: MPMusicPlayerController {
        if musicPlayer_Lazy == nil {
            musicPlayer_Lazy = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()
            let center = NotificationCenter.default
            center.addObserver(
                self,
                selector: #selector(self.playingItemDidChange),
                name: NSNotification.Name.MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange,
                object: musicPlayer_Lazy)
            musicPlayer_Lazy!.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
        }

        return musicPlayer_Lazy!
    }

    //If song changes
    func playingItemDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
        //somehow call updateSongInfo() method from 2nd class
    }

    //Get song metadata
    func getSongData() -> (UIImage, String?, String?) {
        let nowPlaying = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem

        //...some code
        return (albumImage, songName, artistAlbum)
    }

    func updateProgressBar() -> (Int?, Float?){
        let nowPlaying = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem
        var songDuration: Int?
        var elapsedTime: Float?

        songDuration = nowPlaying?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration) as? Int
        elapsedTime = Float(musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime)

        return(songDuration, elapsedTime)
    }
}
```

2) View controller which should be updated when Player Controller get notification

```
//  MainViewController.swift
//  player

import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    let playerController = PlayerController()
    @IBOutlet weak var albumView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var songLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var artistAlbum: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Start updating progress bar
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5,
                         target: self,
                         selector: #selector(MainViewController.updateProgressBar),
                         userInfo: nil,
                         repeats: true)
    }

    private func updateSongInfo(){
        (albumView.image!, songLabel.text, artistAlbum.text) = playerController.getSongData()
    }

    private func updateProgressBar(){
        (progressBar.maximumValue, progressBar.value) = playerController.playingItemProgress()
}
}
```

**Solution for Swift 3:**

In NowPlayingController:

```
let newSongNotifications = NSNotification(name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateSongNotification"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)

func playingItemDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(newSongNotifications as Notification)
}
```

And in other controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateSongInfo), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateSongNotification"), object: nil)
}
```

Comment: How "NowPlayingController" and "MainViewController" are related in your program.Does any one of these classes create object of other ?.If not who owns those objects do you have other classes ?

Comment: These classes are in separate .swift files and do not have any relations except for the 'let playerController = PlayerController()' call. NowPlayingController is to track systemMusicPlayer events and to control it. MainViewController is to handle the UI from "Main.storyboard" - to update interface when songs changes and to define buttons actions. I actually have other .swift files like PageController, but they don't affect these classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post a notification from within your custom object where you need it:

```
    let notification = NSNotification(name:"doSomethingNotification", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
    NotificationCenter.defaultCenter.postNotification(notification)
```

And then in your other view controller in which you want to execute something in response to this notification, you tell it to observe the notification in `viewDidLoad()`. The selector you pass in is the method you want to be executed when the notification is received.

```
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.doSomething), name: "doSomethingNotification", object: nil)
    }
```

Comment: That what I was looking for, thanks!
Also here is code for Swift 3:
'let newSongNotifications = NSNotification(name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateSongNotification"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)

func playingItemDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(newSongNotifications as Notification)
}'
And in other module:
'override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateSongInfo), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateSongNotification"), object: nil)
}'

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate method to update MainViewController

Comment: Hi Albin, can you give me some example? I'm fairly new to the Swift and it's hard for me to see how it should be arranged for my task.